# PHP form validation error

Tags: php, forms, associative-array

Hi I am a beginner in programming with PHP and while I was trying to do some form validation I got this error:

"Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web\Proiecte\Cristina\formular.php on line 67"

This is my HTML for this section:

```
<form id ="fabrica" action="formular.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="unu"/>
</form>
```

And this is my php code:

```
if(isset($_POST('unu'))){
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>a mers</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be better with square brackets `$_POST['unu']`

Comment: You have change right syntax post variables.. $_POST['unu']

Answer (score 6, accepted):

_POST is an associative array (a superglobal)

You can access its content using the regular array syntax

```
$_POST['unu']
```

instead of

```
$_POST('unu')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['unu']))
```

Use square brackets

Answer (score 1):

post values are stored as array

to acces them you need to write as

```
               if(isset($_POST['unu'])){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>a mers</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
```